# windows 10 скорость копирования файлов (после удаления McAfee)

Tags: php, windows, файловый-ввод-вывод

Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с чем-то похожим: есть дешевенький ноутбук HP с SSD. С покупки около месяца. На нем был установлен McAfee и в последнее время он стал клянчить что-то там продлить в ответ на что был немедленно удален Панель управления -> Удаление программы. По очевидному совпадению с этого момента явно замедлились примерно раза в 2 операции копирования файлов по крайней мере средствами PHP (OpenServer, Yii2, AssetManager публикация ресурсов). Кроме удаления McAfee за данный промежуток времени других изменений не было, ПО Yii2-PHP бралось для теста из недавних бэкапов. Да в остальных случаях windows-копирования файлов субъективно как-будто стало медленнее. Может McAfee при удалении изменил какие-нибудь windows параметры?

Comment: пробовали делать откат? проверить до\после чтоб наверняка? какой объем у ссд

Comment: дак вы не субъективно, а объективно замерьте скорость.

Comment: ssd 256. откат винды не делал (и не хотелось бы). думал может кто что видел такое или слышал или догадывается )))

Comment: объективно замерял openserver yii2 assetmanager публикация ресурсов в 2 раза медленнее

Comment: вообще откат это конечно хорошо но какой откат он же мне снесет все к нулевому состоянию я там не вижу каких то автоматических контрольных точек до удаления mcafee или как оно там windows 10 работает?

Answer (score 2):

Windows Defender, господа! Воду мутил. Добавил исключение на требуемый каталог и все зашуршало по прежнему. Так-то!